# Java application to lock the mouse to single screen in a dual screen setup

Tags: java

I have a java application running on screen 2. I want to add code to my application such that mouse is locked to monitor 1 (I have 2 monitors connected to my window machine).

Can someone point me to the code which will enable me to lock the mouse to a single screen.

Comment: I have a feeling that Java would not be the best tool for doing something like this, not even in the top 90% of available tools, since Java was designed to be as OS-ignorant ("agnostic") as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution that comes to my mind is to monitor the position of mouse and move it back to the primary monitor if it is not presently on that monitor. Here is some code to get you started:

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import java.awt.PointerInfo;
import java.awt.Robot;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException, InterruptedException {
        //Get the primary monitor from the environment
        GraphicsDevice gd = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
        //Create and start the thread that monitors the position of the mouse
        Thread observerThread = new Thread(new Observer(gd));
        observerThread.start();

    }

    private static class Observer implements Runnable{
        private GraphicsDevice mainMonitor;
        private Robot robot;
        int width, height;

        public Observer(GraphicsDevice gd){
            mainMonitor = gd;
            width = mainMonitor.getDisplayMode().getWidth();
            height = mainMonitor.getDisplayMode().getHeight();
            try {
                robot = new Robot();
            } catch (AWTException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true){
                //Check the monitor on which the mouse is currently displayed
                PointerInfo pointerInfo = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
                GraphicsDevice device = pointerInfo.getDevice();
                if(!mainMonitor.equals(device)){
                    //If the mouse is not on the primary monitor move it to the center of the primary monitor.
                    robot.mouseMove(width/2, height/2);
                }
                //Wait a while before checking the position of the mouse again.
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Some things to consider with this approach:

1. What if the various monitors do not have the same resolution? This is why I chose to move the mouse to the center of the primary monitor when it strays from the primary monitor. If you want to try to create an experience for the user closer to locking the mouse to the primary screen then you have to determine what to do when the mouse is moved to a screen that has a larger or smaller resolution than the primary screen.
2. What if you have more than 2 monitors? If you want to try to create an experience for the user closer to locking the mouse to the primary screen then you would need a way to determine the relative positions of the monitors. E.g. monitor 2 is left of monitor 1, monitor 3 is right of monitor 1 so that you could move the mouse back to the edge of monitor 1 on the appropriate side - either right or left depending on which screen the mouse was on.

Hope this helps get you started!